# How to remove the backslash after add a word"specifics" in the urlpattern from the Django tutorial 03?

Tags: python, django

[django tutorial 03](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/)

I follow the tutorail and add the word "specifics" in the urlpattern

```
# added the word 'specifics'
path('specifics/<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

But after I add it, the url in the index turns to like this :

http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/specifics/1//

There are 2 forward slashes in the end.Why? Is that a bug? How to fix it?

Comment: Those are not backslashes, they are forward slashes.

Comment: Either remove or update the 
app_name = 'polls' so this `polls` will go away, also, remove the last forward slash in `specifics/<int:question_id>/` so it will be `specifics/<int:question_id>`

Comment: I have tried this, but it will cause othe issues